# How to access the container view in its corresponding view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uicontainerview

I've got a parent view and two container views from it. And now I want to access the container view from its corresponding view controller (I create them in storyboard). I've tried to use `self.view` but it makes no sense. Any idea?

Comment: assign a class to view controller and then in the storyboard add a segue from container view to the view controller it will automatically load data from that  view controller into the container view

Comment: Yeah I know and I've done what you said. But I want to do some work in the corresponding view controller based on its container view's size.

Comment: so then get the size of the container and then with the segue in prepare for segue function pass the size to the viewcontroller and then set the size accordingly

Comment: Could you please show me the code script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that I've understood you correctly, but have you tried

```
self.view.subviews
```

For example you can set `.tag` for your container view, and find your view with code:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if (view.tag == yourTag) {
        //Container view logic
    }
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: It seems not work, for I NSLoged the `views` but their frames are all (0,0,0,0) and their hidden properties are all YES, which are different with my configuration.